# Loading .csv files into python using sklearn

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I am trying to import .csv file into scikit-learn. I know that I can use pandas, but don't know how to use 
my data set looks like this

```
0.9731  0.9695  0.9857  0.9909  0.9448  0.9367  0.9976  0.9672
0.9723  0.9767  0.9767  0.9656  0.9625  0.9589  0.9429  0.9319
0.9858  0.9886  0.9883  0.9784  0.9729  0.9683  0.9567  0.9428
0.9834  0.9838  0.9886  0.9782  0.9729  0.9629  0.9849  0.9456
```

I am working on windows. I am new to the sklearn, I was able to easily load the inbuilt datasets and work on it, but not able to load my own datasets.

Comment: AFAIK, scikit-learn with pandas objects, so use pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the `io.StringIO` bit which is just a way to pass a string as a file buffer, you can load this easily calling [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) and pass params `header=None` and `sep='\s+'`:

```
In [3]:

import io
import pandas as pd
temp = '''0.9731  0.9695  0.9857  0.9909  0.9448  0.9367  0.9976  0.9672
0.9723  0.9767  0.9767  0.9656  0.9625  0.9589  0.9429  0.9319
0.9858  0.9886  0.9883  0.9784  0.9729  0.9683  0.9567  0.9428
0.9834  0.9838  0.9886  0.9782  0.9729  0.9629  0.9849  0.9456'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), header=None, sep='\s+')
df
Out[3]:
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
0  0.9731  0.9695  0.9857  0.9909  0.9448  0.9367  0.9976  0.9672
1  0.9723  0.9767  0.9767  0.9656  0.9625  0.9589  0.9429  0.9319
2  0.9858  0.9886  0.9883  0.9784  0.9729  0.9683  0.9567  0.9428
3  0.9834  0.9838  0.9886  0.9782  0.9729  0.9629  0.9849  0.9456
```

I don't know what these values are but you can either assign columns directly: `df.columns = [some_col_list]` or pass a list to `read_csv`, `names=some_col_list`

To pass specific columns to sklearn just index them e.g. if your columns had names `col1....coln` then you call `clf.fit(df['col1'], df['coln'])` assuming col1 and coln are your X and y columns respectively

Comment: thank u so much for your answer, i would like to add that , whenever i try to add a csv file , though it is present ,the program ,it says the file does not exist. i tried the following code but it throws IOError  kindly help  >>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
>>> train_df = pd.read_csv("attendees1.csv")            it shows "IOError: File attendees1.csv does not exist"

Comment: @Sarah you'll have to explain that, it could be that your filepath is malformed, generally you should use forwards slashes e.g. `'c:/data/myData.csv'` if you use backslashes then you have to escape them e.g. `'c:\\data\\myData.csv'` or pass a raw string: `r'c:\data\myData.csv'`

Comment: by default python uses the executing folder as the current location so you have to pass the complete path to your csv, you can print the current working directory using this: `import sys print(sys.path)` will list all the paths it can see, it's likely that if your csv is not in one of these paths then it can't find it, best to provide the full path

Comment: could u please explain it

Comment: Which bit did you not understand? you need to pass the full path to your csv: `train_df = pd.read_csv(r"c:\myFolder\attendees1.csv")` so wherever attendees1.csv is located you need to pass the full path to it

Comment: could u please explain it . I will rephrase what my doubt is .  I have a file named "attendee.csv" , i want to use this file or import this file and process the file using sklearn algorithms. can u please write an example code for this so that i can understand well. thank u so much

Comment: Sorry it's still unclear and lots of comments does not help, if you have another question please another question

Answer (score 0):

After you've loaded the csv in as a pandas DataFrame, you may want to transform the data into a matrix format.

```
csv_matrix = df.as_matrix()
```

For instance several models such as sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression require data in matrix format: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html